# Rails Nested Attributes and Model Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Looking at the example of `form_for` from the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), I see this example:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  First name: <%= person_form.text_field :first_name %>
  Last name : <%= person_form.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= fields_for @person.permission do |permission_fields| %>
    Admin?  : <%= permission_fields.check_box :admin %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I tried copying this template, but noticed that in order to get the update to work correctly, I had to change the `field_for` line to

```
 <%= person_form.fields_for @person.permission do |permission_fields| %>
```

Any idea why they are showing the `fields_for` without the parent form variable in front (`person_form`)?

The examples later in the docs show it with the parent form variable.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a typo. You should also be able to do `person_form.fields_for :permission`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is correct with `person_form`. think of it as the formtag and you just assign the inputs to the form. all the names of the form get set like this (person[attribute]). `fields_for` without `person_form` would create other name like (permission[admin]) - this would fail because the permission object is not connected with the person. through the `person_form.fields_for` the names get right (person[permission][admin]). you get the nested attribute without doing anything more.